# pipelinedb aggregates in where clause

Tags: pipelinedb

Im am using pipelinedb for testing some analysis of data streams from sensors.
I want to be able, as an example, to find events in a stream that are defined by an aggregate. E.g. find events where the difference between max(temperature) and min(temparature) in the last 5 minutes exceeds a certain range.

When trying to put aggregates in the WHERE clause I get an error message saying something like 'aggregates not allowed in continuous views where clasues'

Am I missing something here or is it just not possible?

Otherwise I like pipelinedb very very much!

Well, pipelinedb says: "continuous queries don't support HAVING clauses".

What I'm  trying to do is the following:

I have a stream named geo_vital_stream, which sends some sensor data along with a geolocation. At the moment I am interested

```
insert into geo_vital_stream (device_id, user_id, measured_at, heartrate, energy, eda, lon, lat)  VALUES( 'A005D8-E4 2.0',1,'2015-10-08 15:04:33.134000+02',96.8497201823,351.056269367,0.505791,8.07154018407,52.9531484103 );
```

My cv looks like this:

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS VIEW cv_sensor_eda AS 
SELECT user_id::integer, 
       MAX(eda::numeric) -  MIN(eda::numeric) as range_eda

FROM geo_vital_stream
WHERE (measured_at > clock_timestamp() - interval '1 minutes')
GROUP BY user_id
```

Now, I am interested only in those "events", where the range (range_eda execeeds a certain value in the last minute.)

Answer (score 0):

Using an aggregate in a `WHERE` clause actually isn't legal SQL. That is accomplished using a `HAVING` clause, but it doesn't seem like that's what you need here. Since aggregates compute values across multiple rows, it's not clear to me how you'd retrieve individual events based on aggregates (`min`, `max`) across multiple events. Could you provide an example of what each event looks like?

Comment: Well, pipelinedb says: "continuous queries don't support HAVING clauses".

What I'm  tryoing to filter out is the following:

I have a stream named geo_vital_stream, which sends some sensor data along with a geolocation. At the moment I am interested